# javascript, edit code image value checker

Tags: javascript, image

This code i put it in the HTML page for check the file value, and I want to add some secure values in the code

I need to edit this code:

```
 <script>
window.onload = function () {   var form = document.getElementById('forms'),       
imageInput = document.getElementById('img1');
    form.onsubmit = function () {     
    var isValid = /\.jpe?g$/i.test(imageInput.value); 
        if (!isValid) {      
         alert('Non allowed!');     
         }    
           return isValid;   }; };
</script>
```

I need to add more file values, like: gif, png, pdf, psd, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **OR**

```
/\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|pdf|psd)$/i
```

Example:

```
var isValid = /\.(jpe?g|gif|png|pdf|psd)$/i.test(imageInput.src);
```

Comment: i see that, but when i use it in my code it's not work, but when i try old code with jpg only it's work good

idon't know where is th wrong but your code is work will in your ex.  :)

Comment: I have checked the code and discovered that is an error in my code, you code is correct :)
Thank you very much for help

Comment: @rixlinux http://jsfiddle.net/SuFpg/2/ I noticed that you are trying to get the value attribute of an image, this will not work. The code in the fiddle gets the src attribute but it works just fine.